# Problems opening documents using SharePoint forms based authentication

Tags: sharepoint, forms-authentication, wss-3.0

I am trying to build a WSS 3.0 site.

I am having difficulty with the dialog box that pops up when I try to check out a document. 
I tried to solve this by enabling forms based authentication but when I click on the document, Microsoft Word opens and I get garbage (MS Office also fails).

All I want to accomplish is to log into my WSS 3.0 site from any computer and when I'm logged in, edit and upload documents without having the dialog box interrupt me.

How can this be accomplished?

Note: WSS 3.0 is installed in Windows Server 2008, Vista Clients and MS Office 2007.

Comment: Are all the machines you want to access WSS from on the same domain?

Comment: no JP,

i want to access it from any computer on the internet. (i think i know where you're going, security settings in internet explorer? i already tried that).

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the popup you need to do that IE  setting. I am afraid that for Internet site it wont help. If you change to FBA, its a different story, refer [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2009/05/13/update-on-sharepoint-forms-based-authentication-fba-and-office-client.aspx)  for more information.

Answer (score 0):

By garbage do you mean that you see something like a forms login screen inside the document you try to open? If so, one way to fix it is to modify your login screen so users are always given a persistent cookie instead of a session one. There is also a way to have a forms login box appear prior to opening documents (Kusek has linked to information about it in his response).